# create executable with py2exe from a script that imports openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, openpyxl

I am building a console application that writes `*.xlsx` files.  Ideally (and planning for future functionality) I would like to also read existing files and write a modified version out.  Therefore, I felt that the python package `openpyxl` would be the best among available options, because it has both read and write capabilities.

Unfrozen code works as expected.

While freezing the code with `py2exe` produces an executable without major issue, it crashes when run.  The result is the same for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the environment.

I am developing with:

- Python 3.4 (Anaconda)
- `py2exe` == 0.9.2.2
- `openpyxl` == 2.3.0-b1
- Windows 7

Test files are:

```
""" main_openpyxl.py """
from openpyxl import Workbook

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('creating a workbook')
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws['A1'] = 'foo'
    wb.save('test.xlsx')
    print('done')
```

and

```
""" setup.py """
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['main.py'],
    options={
        'py2exe': {
            'bundle_files': 2
        }
    }
)
```

Note, using an alternative package (`xlsxwriter`) does produce a working executable:

```
""" main_xlsxwriter.py """
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('creating a workbook')
    wb = Workbook('test.xlsx')
    ws = wb.add_worksheet()
    ws.write('A1', 'foo')
    wb.close()
    print('done')
```

However this package explicitly only creates `*.xlsx` files.

Also worth mentioning, I am *purposefully avoiding* using `pandas`.

Thus, can anyone suggest a solution that works with `openpyxl`?

Comment: No error messages? I think py2exe writes a "exe-name.log" logfile when crashing... or something similar.

Comment: I get a dialog that says the following and nothing more:  [Window Title]
main.exe

[Main Instruction]
main.exe has stopped working

[Content]
Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.

[^] Hide problem details  [Check online for a solution and close the program] [Close the program]

Comment: The problem is discussed here: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/498/ It is related to the use of a constant that is visible both to openpyxl's setup.py and the library itself and where Python's packaging is deficient. You'll need to find a workaround for this.

Comment: @Charlie, thanks for this information. I happened to also try with openpyxl 2.0.2 (the newest version that conda will install), which the issue implied should work, but got the same result.

Comment: @oddHypothesis, were you able to get this working?